# Change special characters in Python from raw_input

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, raw-input

I'm writing a program to get all file from folder and output in by size. But I have a problem with getting path from raw_input.

For example when user enters: `D:\Mykola\desktop\remove\OLD` or `C:\Users\mykola.borysyuk\Desktop\1.7.2`
 Python sees `\r` and think it's a special character, so that leads to an error.

So my question is: how do I replace all "\" from raw_input to "/"

So that I get this as output:  `D:/Mykola/desktop/remove/OLD`, `C:/Users/mykola.borysyuk/Desktop/1.7.2`

The correct answer was named by HamZa

**str.replace('\\', '/')**

Comment: Isn't this solved by using some basic replace function "\\" -> "/" ?

Comment: As i see. It cant. Because for me a.replace("\\", "/") doesn't work. Try with different numbers of \

Comment: Try with 4 backslashes "\\\\" -> "/"

Comment: After replace string like this : a = 'D:\Mykola\desktop\remove\OLD' . Became a="emove\OLD\desktop"

Comment: `raw_input` will not interpret escape sequences. Please show your code, what you have been trying.

Comment: I edit my post in order to show you

Comment: Sorry guys!! That was my bad! HaMza tell correct answer!((( I guess i just got confused by my brain.   str.replace('\\', '/') works fine

Comment: raw_input doesn't do any interpreting of the input, so entering \r should be no problem whatsoever. There must be something else going on.